# How to smoothly combine objects at a right angle?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make a walkway with planks for a game. As part of this, I need to make a walkway with a right angle. As such, I want to make a clean line where the planks heading in different directions combine cleanly. The picture should more clearly show the problem. I've tried creating a triangle and booleaning the planks, but that ended up not working properly. I used a cut tool to cut the planks as can be seen in the image. I'm stuck on where to go from here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I personally think the imperfections in your joined planks look good.

However for a precise approach consider the following. The [Knife Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-tool) has the option to cut in steps of 45°.

1. Go into edit mode. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
2. Use the Knife Tool <kbd>K</kbd> to cut a 45 degree angle by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> once to activate snapping duration the operation.
3. Remove the vertices which are not needed. <kbd>X</kbd>
4. Snap the cursor to the outer corner where the planks join. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected*
5. Select all <kbd>A</kbd> and duplicate the geometry <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Let it rest in the same place. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>
6. Activate *Cursor as Pivot* <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd>, then rotate the duplicated geometry 90 degree around the cursor pivot. <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.
7. Mirror it in Y. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>
8. Remove the double vertices. <kbd>W</kbd>><kbd>R</kbd>

[image: cutting planks]